# Is it all right with my input filters ?

Tags: input, filter

> Hi Folks,i am new to php ,just finished php courses on codecademy xD
>   ,so the question is : Do i have critical errors in my validation? or i
>   can use it though it is bad written? I just wanna know can i use my
>   form or i need to re-write it because it is vulnerable? Dont wanna
>   waste your time,sorry ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>                
            <meta charset="utf-8">        
            <title>Digital Agency</title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <meta name="description" content="Add your business website description here">
            <meta name="keywords" content="Add your, business, website, keywords, here">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

            <!-- favicon -->  
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
            <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

            <!-- google fonts -->
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700,800,900%7CMerriweather:400,400italic,300,300italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <!-- Font icons -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/elegant-font-icon.css">

            <!-- stylesheet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap.css">        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/animate.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/owl.carousel.css">


            <!-- style switcher -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/style-switcher.css">
            <!-- Custom styles for this template -->        
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/blue.css" title="blue" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/blue-2.css" title="blue-2" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/purple.css" title="purple" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/green.css" title="green" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/green-2.css" title="green-2" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/yellow.css" title="yellow" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/orange.css" title="orange" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/red.css" title="red" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/red-2.css" title="red-2" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/red-3.css" title="red-3" media="screen"/>        
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/pink.css" title="pink" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/pink-2.css" title="pink-2" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/beige.css" title="beige" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/midnight.css" title="midnight" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/black.css" title="black" media="screen"/>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>        
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/modernizr.custom.js"></script>


            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/html5-3.6-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->


    <script>
    function loadXMLDocname()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com/ajaxname.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    function loadXMLDocemail()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com/ajaxemail.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    function loadXMLDocsuccess()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com/ajaxsuccess.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    function loadXMLDocnosuccess()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com/ajaxnosuccess.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>    
    <body>
    <div class="row">            
                  <fieldset id="contactform" class="wow bounce" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0.5s"> 
                  <form method="post" action="<?php $url='http://example.com/formtest.php';echo htmlspecialchars($url);?>">

                    <div id="form_result"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Your email">
                      </div>                
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Your Number">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">         
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="5" id="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">                    
                          <button type="submit"  onclick="loadXMLDoc()" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"  id="submit">SUBMIT</button>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                  </fieldset>
                  </div>
                  </body>
    </html>

    <?php

    $a=mysql_connect('xxxxx','xxxx','xxxx');

    $b=mysql_select_db('xxxxx',$a);

    if (!$b){
    echo 'no connection db ';

    }

    if ($_POST){

    $n=htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    $e=htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $p=intval($_POST['phone']);
    $m=htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);



    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)&&filter_var($_POST['message'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)){



    echo '<script>loadXMLDocnosuccess();</script>';

    }


    if (filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)&&filter_var($_POST['message'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)){


    $i=mysql_query('INSERT INTO yup SET name="'.$n.'",email="'.$e.'",phone='.$p.',message="'.$m.'"');

    echo '<script>loadXMLDocsuccess();</script>';

    }




    if(!$_POST['name']){


    echo '<script>loadXMLDocname();</script>';

    }

    if(!$_POST['email']){


    echo '<script>loadXMLDocemail();</script>';

    }

    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Just a quick tip, you have to much link to .css remember thats not a good practice since you are telling the browser to download each file 1x1 on every load, also please copy/paste the code inside a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and put the link here on the comments/question

Comment: Thanks pal ,if i could understand what is the jsfiddle =) But anyway i got the idea about css.Thanks

Comment: on jsFiddle you can just put all your `.html .css and .js` code link to whatever CDN (e.i bootstrap) or select some library jsfiddle have for you (i.e jQuery) and run/save/share your code, **why i should do that?** its more easy for the stack community to `test/help` you in each issue you have(sorry for the horrible english)